# create branches in anypoint design center to modify the RAML changes

Tags: raml, anypoint-platform

I want to create branches for modifying the exisiting raml, 
can any one help me how to create a new branch before modifying new changes directly to the master instead I can create feature branch or some other branch and
 also I would like to know how to merge the new create branches to the existing branch

Example:

Master>UAT>STAGE>INT>DEV--- I need to create this as constant 
and create feature whenever there are any changes requested

I need to create all this branches
but I have only one branch as Master

So if any of them want to update existing raml they should be able to create one feature branch and sent and approval request to merge any of the existing.

Answer (score 1):

In Anypoint API Designer you can create branches from the master branch, by following the instructions at https://docs.mulesoft.com/design-center/design-branching, however note that the same page mentions explicitly that you can not merge changes from a branch back into master.